# Google Web App alerts have scripts.googleusercontent.com says

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm building a Web App on the Google  Apps Script platform

When I summon JavaScript alerts e.g.
`window.alert('Thankyou for submitting your details. You will now be taken to the grammar test')`
it will give me a message at the top of the alert saying *randomString scripts.googleusercontent.com says*

[image: screenshot]

This looks messy and unprofessional so I would like to get rid of it before giving to my client

How can I override it?